# Selenium-Python: Switching between iframes causes a non-functional modal to remain on the page

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, automation

I have a segment of the automated script written in python utilizing Selenium. A model appears on a page that I am automating, and in that model, there is an iframe used to handle uploading a piece of media. So I switch to the iframe, switch back to default content, then continue on to the next model that appears after the piece of media has been uploaded.

However, it's around this point that a model appears on the page that is not functional. For example, it looks just like the model from before the upload occurred, and I can't manually close the modal at all. It draws over the newly updated model, even though the test will successfully pass. I'm not sure how to go about fixing this. Here is the code segment:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#closeAlert").click()

startTime = time.time()
WebDriverWait(driver, 4).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.uploadButton.uploadBtn.clearfloat"))
)
endTime = time.time()
print("'Upload Completed Media' modal draw time: %.3f secs." % (endTime - startTime))

driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe#upload-iframe"))
uploadField = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#mediaFile")
uploadField.send_keys(r"C:\SVN\test_suites\aePortal_ui\Resources\QATAE0000001289-001_hr.pdf")

driver.switch_to_default_content()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.uploadButton.uploadBtn.clearfloat").click()

startTime = time.time()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#closeUpModal"))
)
endTime = time.time()
print("Upload Completed Media upload time: %.3f secs." % (endTime - startTime))

driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe#upload-iframe"))

upload_status = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p.upMsg")

if(upload_status.text == "File(s) successfully uploaded."):
    print("Completed Media uploaded successfully. Pass.")
else:
    print("Completed Media did not upload successfully. FAIL.")

driver.switch_to_default_content()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#closeUpModal").click()
```

Comment: the simple solution to this kind of errors is often sleep statement between the actions that cause the problem

Comment: Are you saying that the software has a bug that it shows an unknown modal, and you can't close that unknown modal?

Comment: @Buaban - I doubt its the software itself causing a buggy modal to appear. It seems like its likely related to a timing issue.

Comment: @AviahLaor I'll try to add a wait or sleep statement when switching between frames and see if that works.